# How to set publishing path of a WSO2 server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wso2

After installing a WSO2 server in Eclipse I can open an overview of the server where I can see and set the publishing interval, timeouts, launch configuration etc.
For a TOMCAT I can also specify the deployment path and much more. For a WSO2/Carbon server I can only see *General Information* (like launch configuration), *Ports*, *Publishing* (intervals), *Timeouts* and *Other*. 
Is there a way to see more like I can see for a TOMCAT?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported right now as eclipse overview is the only way to view/specify the above for WSO2 components.